# How can I make a webmail be my default email client?

Tags: email, gmail, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make links to email addresses open Gmail instead of Evolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5882/can-i-make-links-to-email-addresses-open-gmail-instead-of-evolution)

I would have liked to make Gmail be my default email client, or mail program. In that case I would be able to open a Firefox window containing a new message writer, every time I click on a 'mailto:' hyperlink.

How should I do it?