# How to set GMail as default Mail Application

Tags: email, gmail, default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make links to email addresses open Gmail instead of Evolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5882/can-i-make-links-to-email-addresses-open-gmail-instead-of-evolution)

Is it possible to set the Default Mail Application to be GMail within Firefox?

Currently, every time I click an email link in a program (or in Unity's default Dash/Lense) I get Evolution starting up.