# Changing email application in Preferred Applications to GMail?

Tags: 11.04, email, gmail

I'm trying to change the Preferred Application for email. I have installed the package desktop-webmail, but there is no new option under System - Preferences - Preferred Application as you would expect, infact, there is only one option there, only Evolution.

According to [this post](http://crunchbang.org/archives/2007/12/04/gmail-as-default-email-client-in-ubuntu/) it should be possible to set a custom application, but no option is available.

Is it possible to setup GMail as Preferred email app so that File -> Send by email works in gnome apps?

This seems to be a dup of [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5882/can-i-make-links-to-email-addresses-open-gmail-instead-of-evolution) here, Thing is that this works fine in 10.10, but in 11.04 this method no longer work. My post above is meant for 11.04 and the question is still valid.

Comment: Regarding the 1st part: did you do a **sudo update-alternatives --config mail-client** to see if it is then added? I know I needed to do that to have Opera show under browsers.

Comment: The geek page that is used in your link (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/set-gmail-as-default-mail-client-in-ubuntu/) works for me!

Comment: @jorge & @Rinzwind, I checked in 10.10 and works fine there. I therefore retagged this issue to 11.04 which is the version I have trouble. The UI for Preferred App seems to have changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To set GMail as the default for mailto links in Ubuntu 11.10 :

1. Install gnome-gmail
2. Edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add the line below:

   x-scheme-handler/mailto=gnome-gmail.desktop;
3. Open *System Info* (use the Dash) and under *Default Applications* change *Mail* to *Gnome Gmail*

[image: Screenshot of System Info]

Comment: Hero! Confirmed this works in 11.04 :D

Comment: is there a way to open this menu through the command line ?

Comment: @viyyer: I guess setting the key mimeapps.listx-scheme-handler/mailto to "gnome-gmail.desktop;" in the section [Default Applications] in mimeapps.list should do it. This is what the gui application changes when you choose gmail.

Comment: Second step is not necessary, at least in Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: 13.04: sudo apt-get install gnome-gmail; once you open the first mail by clicking a corresponding link in the browser, it asks you if it should be set as default. Choose 'yes' and be happy :-)

Comment: In recent versions of Ubuntu (tested on 15.10), you can access this configuration dialog from the commandline by using the `unity-control-center` command, and choosing the "Details" icon.

Answer (score 10):

Just install gnome gmail

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-gmail
```

Then open it.

You should get a prompt asking whether you want it to be your default mail client.  Say Yes.  Works on 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

Just a slight alteration of funkymonk's post works.
First install gnome-gmail:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-gmail
```

Then open the following:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

You want to add:

```
x-scheme-handler/mailto=gnome-gmail.desktop;
```

underneath both "Added Associations" and "Default Applications".

If there is something like

```
x-scheme-handler/mailto=userapp-Evolution-RZZYTV.desktop
```

there, you should replace this, otherwise just add the code. 
Then save and close and it should now work.

Answer (score 2):

Check this post on WebUpd8.org: [Gnome Gmail](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/gnome-gmail-allows-gmail-to-be-selected.html).
It allows Gmail to be selected as the default mail application for Gnome.

Comment: Upvoting because you are the only guy who signed on in the last decade out of all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Open GMail on Chorme.
On right side of search bar you'll see an 'eye' icon(highlighted on the image). Click on it.

**Note** - If you don't see the 'eye' icon. Go below of this answer to solve this issue.

[image]

You'll see this pop-up

[image]

Choose allow and click on Done.

That's it. Now GMail is your default  email opener.

---

### If you don't see the 'eye' icon

If you don't see the 'eye' icon on the search bar goto the **Chrome Settings** then search **Protocol Handlers** then somewhere you'll find this Protocol Handlers section(depending on version of Chrome) then select **Sites can ask to handle protocols**.

Now go back to start of this answer then follow the mentioned steps.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To change the default email app:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
vi mimeapps.list
```

Which should output the following

```
1 
2 [Default Applications]
3 x-scheme-handler/mailto=userapp-Evolution-RZZYTV.desktop
4 
5 [Added Associations]
6 x-scheme-handler/mailto=userapp-Evolution-RZZYTV.desktop;
```

Now if you want Thunderbird to be your default e-mail application then make the following changes:

```
1 
2 [Default Applications]
3 x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird
4 
5 [Added Associations]
6 x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird;
```

Now whenever you click a mailto link it fires up Thunderbird.

Cheers !!

Comment: He wants webmail ;)