# How can I make Claws Mail the preferred email client?

Tags: 11.04, email, claws

I have read here, [Changing email application in Preferred Applications to GMail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40004/changing-email-application-in-preferred-applications), how to access `mimeapps.list` but I cannot figure out what needs to be entered for Claws Mail to act as preferred. I have tried

```
x-scheme-handler/mailto=claws-mail.desktop
```

and

```
x-scheme-handler/mailto=claws-mail
```

but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the version of Claws-mail from the repositories (ie. 3.7.8-1ubuntu4)?  [Version 3.7.9-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/claws-mail/3.7.9-1ubuntu1) has amongst others this bugfix:

```
Include x-scheme-handler in .desktop file (Closes: #610342)
```

So install this new version and it should work. You can get the lastest version [here](https://launchpad.net/~claws-mail/+archive/ppa) or following these instructions. Add these 2 to your repositories:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/claws-mail/ppa/ubuntu natty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/claws-mail/ppa/ubuntu natty main
```

update your sources list and update/re-install claws-mail. Images:

[image]

[image]

(If sources needed repeat it for the 2nd line)

Comment: I am actually running Claws Mail 3.7.10. Is there some part that maybe is not updated properly. Or is there something else that I need to enter in the mimeapps.list, other than what I have tried?

Comment: If that is the case I would suggest to create a bug report! Acc to the maintainer he thinks it IS working in v9 and up :( sorry